# How to export some data from a database to other, multiple databases?

Tags: sql, database, optimization, synchronization, export

Currently working on a practice project, to simulate a retail store scenario.

We have Database A, containing 10.000 unique articles, in a central database, let's call it the CENTRAL DB.

We need to export 10.000 articles from the REFERENCE DB, to a special Store XX DB, where XX is from 1-10, let's say 10 stores. Basically we would like to store the data somewhere else, locally, but still have it on a central server.

In the CENTRAL DB, we have a table with Articles, Stores, and a JUNCTION TABLE, called ArticleStore, where we hold the columns for the unique articles, that could have different data in each store (price for example).
So that means that for 10.000 unique articles, if we have 10 stores, we could have 10 lines in the ArticleStore for Coca Cola price for example, because each store can have different price.

So coming back to my requirement, each time the Coca Cola article, will have to update the price from 1.99 to 2.99 in the CENTRAL DB, it should automatically export the updated data to each LOCAL STORE.

What's the best approach for this solution ? Should I add another column in the JUNCTION TABLE, with a status (0 - for synced with LOCAL DB, or 1 - when it needs to SYNC with LOCAL DB).
Is there any other approach, if I don't want to add another column?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Capturing of changes is called Change Data Capture (CDC). It is whole huge field in DB technologies. It very much depends on the DB engine you are using. The simplest way is to select all rows with CHANGE_DTTM > LAST_CAPTURE, considering that you store CHANGE_DTTM.